# Using complex structure with SOAP

Tags: php, soap, structure

The problem is that I cannot succeed to send an array of class through SOAP to a specific web service that I cannot change his structure.

Here below you'll see the schema of the Soap function:

[image]
http://www.elyotech.com/share/yoni/forum/developpeznet-soap.jpg

Here you'll find the code I'm corresponding to it:

```
$s = new soapclient($URL_WEBSERVICE,array('wsdl'=>true,"trace"=>true));
$params = new stdClass();
$params->loginInfo = new stdClass();
$params->loginInfo->UserName =  'username';

    $params->loginInfo->Password =  'password';
    $params->loginInfo->LanguageCode =  'en';
    $params->reservation = new stdClass();
    $params->reservation->EmailRecipient2 = 'yonia@yopmail.com';
    $params->reservation->EmailRecipient3 = 'yonia2@yopmail.com';
    $params->reservation->FirstName = 'Yoni'
    foreach($extras as $id=>$extra)
    {
        $params->Extras[$id]= new stdClass();
        $params->Extras[$id]->SelectedExtra = new stdClass();
        $params->Extras[$id]->ExtensionData = new stdClass();
        $params->Extras[$id]->SelectedExtra->Amount = 1;
        $params->Extras[$id]->SelectedExtra->ID = $extra;
    }
```

Here is the SOAP request that is sent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:CreateReservation>
      <ns1:loginInfo>
        <ns1:UserName>monusername</ns1:UserName>
        <ns1:Password>monpass</ns1:Password>
        <ns1:LanguageCode>en</ns1:LanguageCode>
      </ns1:loginInfo>
      <ns1:reservation>
        <ns1:EmailRecipient2>yonia@yopmail.com</ns1:EmailRecipient2>
        <ns1:EmailRecipient3>yonia2@yopmail.com</ns1:EmailRecipient3>
        <ns1:FirstName>Yoni</ns1:FirstName>
      </ns1:reservation>
    </ns1:CreateReservation>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

In this Soap request, I cannot find the `Extras` array of objects.

Do you have any idea of how I should create my object in order to send it correctly?

Comment: You should check the contents of the $params array prior to sending the request (eg, var_dump() it). I don't see any problem with the code, and in fact it adds the "extras" just fine: http://codepad.org/11u4KQU3.   I suspect $extras is not what you expect it is coming into this code.